# Strength as a priority stat for vengeance juggernaut?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm currently leveling a Vengeance Juggernaut and have been looking around at stat priorities so I can be aware of what I need to look for.

I'm seeing a lot of strength on various websites as the #1 stat priority. However under my character panel I have not seen "strength" as a stat?

Did they remove this in an update or something?  What gives? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they did away with Strength (as well as Willpower, Aim, and Cunning, plus combining Crit and Surge) with Patch 4.0.  Now all classes use Mastery instead.  All you need to worry about is choosing the modifications with more Mastery than Endurance (the reverse is for tanks).